# スクロールビューで画像をループさせてタイル上に並べたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview

UIScrollView を使用して画像（黒線内が画面）を以下のように並べて

[image: スクロール前]

スワイプさせたら以下のようにループさせたいです。

[image: スクロール後]

- UIScrollView で画像をタイル上に並べること
- UIScrollView で画像をループさせること

この２つを実現するにはどのようなコードを書けばいいのでしょうか？

Comment: このURLにそれっぽいのがありました。http://qiita.com/caesar_cat/items/f6a60b6bb6880ea18139

Comment: この方法ではUIScrollViewで表示される画面に１つの画像しか表示する事ができません。画面上に複数の画像を表示させる必要があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば、画面幅=320、ボタン幅=72、ボタン同士のマージン=8とすると、

- 1セット分のボタン = (72+8)*5個 = 400
- ループ用のボタン（画面幅分） = 320 / (72+8) = 4個

となるので、ScrollViewに1セット分のボタン（5個）とループ用のボタン（4個）を並べて、
このサイズをcontentSizeに設定します。

```
|<-1セット分 ->|<-ループ用 ->|
+-------------+-----------+
|橙 黃 緑 青 赤  橙 黃 緑 青 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

そして、`UIScrollViewDelegate`の`scrollViewDidScroll:`の中で、下記のようにループ処理を行えばいいと思います。

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    #define _WIDTH (400) //1セット分のボタンのサイズ
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= _WIDTH)
    {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x - _WIDTH, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    }
    else
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0)
    {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x + _WIDTH, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    }
}
```

ループ用のボタンがちょっと無駄ですが、お手軽にループを実現できると思います。